Proving sequences are Cauchy in a metric space
I have concluded that the sequences in b) and c) are both Cauchy with respect to $d$. This is because I deduced that $f(a_1 + \ldots + _n) \geq min\{f(a_1), \ldots, f(a_n)\}$ and used telescoping in both questions. In part c), I deduced that $f(b_{n+1} - b_n) \geq 2n + 1$ for $n \geq 2$, but I'm not sure this is correct. I was just wondering if I have mis-understood this question and my approach is wrong?


Please refrain from adding links, summarise if required.

Hi Jonathan, I just added a link to a picture of the question, it is a very tedious question to write up, can I leave the post as is, or do I have to edit?

Yes that will be ok for now, now that you have over 10 reputation (I upvoted), please add a screenshot of the link picture. Thanks.

Hi Jonathan, How do I add a screenshot of the link picture? Can I just paste into the body of my paragraph?

You can do both, whichever is most suitable to you.

Thanks Jonathan, all done :)
